# keycloak-js adapter manually adding the token

Tags: javascript, keycloak

I dont like redirecting to my keycloak server for logging in I rather have my own web page so I did some digging and found that I can get a token and refresh_token from this endpoint of my keycloak-server

```
`${url}/auth/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;
```

And I have used those tokens and they work.
The thing is that I would have to add a lot of work(ok not that much, but still!!), to refresh the token and all the cool things that the keycloak-js library already does. I was checking to the documentation and I couldnt find anything or understand how to pass the tokens to my Keycloak object.

I tried doing something like this on the init

```
keycloak.init({
        promiseType: 'native',
        token: token,
        refreshToken: refreshToken
})
```

I still dont get not authenticated. It feels like I am missing tons of steps.

If I do something like console.log(keycloak.token) I still get null.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @StijnWesterhof, no I just used the native solutions of angular

Comment: Do you have your keycloak server setup correctly? I think you need PKCE enabled to be able to use refresh tokens. Then you pass `pkceMethod: 'S256'` inside your `init()` method